# Segmentation fault when drawing

Tags: c++, drawing, sfml

My window closes when I draw a sprite.

It's definitely the drawing part of it because when I keep it out of
my code, it works fine, except it doesn't draw my sprite of course.

Also I get this error when running: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I don't know what that means :/ .

And here is my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//create vars
sf::Color bgColour(20, 175, 215);
vector<sf::Sprite> tiles;

void CreateTile(string Texture, int x, int y)
{
    sf::Vector2f Pos(x, y);

    sf::Texture Ftexture;
    Ftexture.loadFromFile(Texture);
    sf::Sprite Tile;
    Tile.setTexture(Ftexture);
    Tile.setPosition(Pos);

    tiles.push_back(Tile);
}

int main()
{
    //create window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "-\\\\-(Game)-//-");

    CreateTile("Recources/grass.png", 40, 40);

    //main loop
    while (window.isOpen()) {

        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {               
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }            
        }

        window.clear(bgColour);
        window.draw(tiles[1]);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to acces an element on the vector that do not exist.

change this

```
window.draw(tiles[1]);
```

to this

```
window.draw(tiles[0]);
```